# RKHS of limit of reproducing kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\{K_n\}$ be a sequence of positive definite kernels such that

1. $K_n\preccurlyeq K_{n+1}$ for all $n$ (it means that $K_{n+1}-K_n$ is a positive definite kernel)
2. They have a limit $K(x,y)=\lim_{n\to \infty}K_n(x,y)$.

If $K$ is a positive definite kernel, we write $\mathcal{H}_K$ for its associated reproducing kernel Hilbert space (RKHS).

My question is: is the following equation true $$\mathcal{H}_K = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{H}_{K_{n}}\,,$$
where $=$ means equality as a set.

And what about decreasing $\{K_n\}$? In other words, $K_n\succcurlyeq K_{n+1}$ and they have a limit $K$. Is it true that $$\mathcal{H}_K=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{H}_{K_n}\,.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "limit of a sequence of increasing sets"? Is it the union? In that case I would bet that the answer is negative. For example, if all $H_{K_n}$ are spaces of smooth functions, then each element of their union is a smooth function. But I guess there are examples for which $H_K$ turns out to be a space which also contains nonsmooth functions. Only guessing, I am not familiar with these concepts.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the comment! Yes, it is the union and I edited the question description.